# Есть ли библиотека по выполнению синтаксического анализа для русского языка в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек, nlp

Есть ли библиотека по выполнению синтаксического анализа для русского языка в Python?

Comment: pymorphy2, nltk

Comment: @MaxU Добавьте ответ

Comment: Вопросы по поиску библиотек должны содержать по возможности больше критериев для выбора. Дополните пожалуйста вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться одним из следующих модулей:

- [pymystem3](https://pypi.org/project/pymystem3/)
- [pymorphy2](https://pypi.org/project/pymorphy2/)
- [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/)

**P.S.** выбор модуля зависит от конкретной задачи.